# Hive unix_timestamp not working for milliseconds in source column

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am using Hive 1.1

The last six digits in a_ingestion_dtm represents milliseconds .

But unix_timestamp hive function gives me same result if i specify the pattern as well

So how do i get a result of unix_timestamp that includes the milliseconds as well

```
 select a_ingestion_dtm,unix_timestamp(a_ingestion_dtm) from omega limit 10;
 +-----------------------------+-------------+--+
 |       a_ingestion_dtm       |     _c1     |
 +-----------------------------+-------------+--+
 | 2019-07-08 16:11:02.076002  | 1562616662  |
 | 2019-07-08 21:07:26.253007  | 1562634446  |
 | 2019-07-08 21:07:14.284     | 1562634434  |
 +-----------------------------+-------------+--+


 select a_ingestion_dtm,unix_timestamp(a_ingestion_dtm,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS') from omega limit 10;

 +-----------------------------+-------------+--+
 |       a_ingestion_dtm       |     _c1     |
 +-----------------------------+-------------+--+
 | 2019-07-08 16:11:02.076002  | 1562616662  |
 | 2019-07-08 21:07:26.253007  | 1562634446  |
 | 2019-07-08 21:07:14.284     | 1562634434  |
 +-----------------------------+-------------+--+
```

Answer (score 0):

[unix_timestamp(string date) returns seconds passed from 1970](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions).

You can concatenate milliseconds part to the bigint returned by unix_timestamp.

Like in this demo:

```
with your_data as (
select stack(3,
'2019-07-08 16:11:02.076002',
'2019-07-08 21:07:26.253007',
'2019-07-08 21:07:14.284'
) as ts
)

select concat_ws('.',cast(unix_timestamp(ts) as string),regexp_extract(ts,'\\.(\\d+)$')) 
  from your_data;
```

Result:

```
OK
1562627462.076002
1562645246.253007
1562645234.284
Time taken: 0.057 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```